# Stored Procedure Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which generates some xml based on 3 parameters: @property_id, @property_component_id and @return_as_xml.  The value for @return_as_xml will be the same for all records which is 0.

I have modified this and now need to run it for multiple Property records based on a specific condition i.e. for active and leased properties.  A one-many relationship exists between property and property_component, so a property can have multiple property_components and does have at least one corresponding record.

I some how need to do a select of the records I want based on the active and leased fields in the Property table.  Select the corresponding property_component_id from the property_component table where a corresponding property_id exists.  I then want to loop through each of the result rows, execute the stored procedure passing in new parameters for each row.

I don't want to modify the stored procedure more than I already have as it is executed from an asp.net console application which requires it to return xml for a single property, ie I don't want alter the stored procedure to return xml for multiple properties.

My stored procedure execution is just the standard generated sql server code:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[p_CPGUploader__FetchXMLForProperty_RCA]
    @property_id = 106016,
    @property_component_id = 108382,
    @return_as_xml = 0

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

How can I modify this to work for my described scenario, how can I get select a recordset then loop through it executing the stored procedure passing based on values from each row of the select?  I come from an asp.net background and my SQL Server skills are extremely limited so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 although I believe the original stored procedure was written in 2004 if that's of any relevance.

Comment: Are you able to convert your Stored Procedure query to a function instead? If you create your XML from a function you can call it from a SELECT statement? What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really can't change the stored procedure, then you can create a loop using a cursor.

I wouldn't advise this course of action unless absolutely necessary though.

```
declare c cursor local read_only for 
select property_component_id from propertiestable

declare @id

open c
fetch from c into @id
while @@fetch_status=0
begin
    EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[p_CPGUploader__FetchXMLForProperty_RCA]
            @property_id = 106016,
            @property_component_id = @id,
            @return_as_xml = 0

   fetch next from c into @id
end
close c
deallocate c
```